# Does Stretch Lite support systemd?

Tags: raspbian, systemd, init, pi-a

Rpi 1 Model A here. I would like to use a [Raspbian image](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/) in my first pi project, and want to configure it to run an executable Java app (`jar` file) at startup.

According to [this article](https://www.dexterindustries.com/howto/run-a-program-on-your-raspberry-pi-at-startup/#systemd) I *might* be able to configure this Java app as a `systemd` startup service, however I wasn't sure if `systemd` was a possible option for Stretch Lite or not. Is it? If not, what's the recommended startup service/method for Raspbian Stretch/Lite?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, the Lite version of Raspbain 9 "Stretch" uses systemd just like 8 "Jessie".
Also I highly recomend using systemd over other options.

Comment: Systemd at least makes handling services much easier, especially when you want to add your own services (service units). Instead of having to write extensive start/stop scripts, not down a few lines of declarations in a service unit file, and the job is done. Need automatic restarts? Just a single definition.